# Error installing the glade library for Haskell via cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, glade, gtk2hs

I am using the most recent version of GHC distributed with Ubuntu 11.10 (7.0.3).

When I try to install glade, I get this:

```
$ cabal install glade
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading glade-0.12.1...
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /tmp/glade-0.12.129125/glade-0.12.1/SetupWrapper.hs, /tmp/glade-0.12.129125/glade-0.12.1/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/glade-0.12.129125/glade-0.12.1/Setup.hs, /tmp/glade-0.12.129125/glade-0.12.1/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/glade-0.12.129125/glade-0.12.1/dist/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring glade-0.12.1...
Preprocessing library glade-0.12.1...
gtk2hsC2hs: UName: root name supply used after saving
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
glade-0.12.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

gtk2hs-buildtools and gtk were successfully installed via cabal. But glade does not install. Is this a bug?

Comment: Which version of gtk2hs-buildtools do you have installed?

Comment: ivanm - I have version gtk2hs-buildtools version 0.12.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to install the latest `glade` package via

```
$ cabal unpack glade
...
$ cd glade-0.12.1
$ runhaskell Setup.hs configure --user
...
$ runhaskell Setup.hs build
...
$ runhaskell Setup.hs build # Note: twice - first build has failed.
...
$ runhaskell Setup.hs install
...
```

Too bad I have no idea what has caused the error.